# Finding all values that add up to 0

Tags: python

I want to build a script that will take a list of accounts and amounts (accounting) and match the amounts that add up to 0. Add the matches to a list of matched items, leave the unmatched items in a sep. list (= unallocated items). It's supposed track open/unallocated items in a given gl (=account) to replace an excel recon.

My code is super slow, even on small datasets with only 77 lines, which is by no means a real world dataset. I give up after 12h of running time. What I tried:

- matching everything against everything in a given gl - super slow
- finding only matching pairs (same amount positive and negative) - fast, but not
  enough matches to replace Excel recons
- try first to match the exact matches and then move on to what is left and match everything against everything - still slow.
- current attempt is to start with an opening balance per account- > add the current month
  transactions to it (equals 142 lines of data) -> start the matching process -> store the final open items in a database. Next month pull the opening balance, add current month transactions, match -> store resulting open items...
  Still incredibly slow.

I added some print statements, but nothing is happening for hours. Here is my code. Any ideas on how to solve my issue more efficiently?

Currently my process is stuck here (terminal output):

```
Progress: 8/27 GLs processed.
Match found for GL 1900: (Decimal('119.4'), Decimal('-119.4'))
Match found for GL 1900: (Decimal('198.35'), Decimal('-198.35'))
Match found for GL 1900: (Decimal('-55.66'), Decimal('-135.68'), Decimal('-180.91'), Decimal('-183.93'), Decimal('-243.68'), Decimal('-277.2'), Decimal('-325.84'), Decimal('-336.43'), Decimal('-423.03'), Decimal('2162.36'))
```

Here is the relevant part:

```
my_list = [{'gl': '1350', 'gl_name': 'Deposits', 'id': '1.23E+04', 'period': '1', 'year': '2005', 'posting_date': '01/01/2005', 'amount': Decimal('28921.90'), 'description': 'Corporate Office rent deposit'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.23E+04', 'period': '11', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '11/01/2023', 'amount': Decimal('6647.27'), 'description': 'Pycharm Subscription 01/01/24-12/31/2024'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.23E+04', 'period': '11', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '11/01/2023', 'amount': Decimal('7552.31'), 'description': 'Weworks - office rent Dec'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.23E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-7552.31'), 'description': 'Exp. Weworks office rent Dec'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.23E+04', 'period': '12', 
'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('23746.02'), 'description': 'National - Car insurance 2024'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('58755.19'), 'description': 'Atlassian - 2024 fees'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 
'amount': Decimal('26610.79'), 'description': 'None'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '11', 'year': '2022', 'posting_date': '11/01/2022', 'amount': Decimal('5538.00'), 'description': 'Pycharm Subscription 01/01/23-12/31/2023'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '2', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '02/28/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 2/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '3', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '03/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 3/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '4', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '04/30/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 4/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '5', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '05/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 5/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '6', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '06/30/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 6/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '7', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '07/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 7/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '8', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '08/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 8/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '9', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '09/30/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 9/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '10', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '10/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 10/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '11', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '11/30/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 11/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-503.45'), 'description': 'Exp Pycharm Subscription 12/23'}, {'gl': '1900', 'gl_name': 'Prepaid Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('-0.05'), 'description': 'Pycharm rounding diff 12/23'}, {'gl': '3060', 'gl_name': 'Accrued Expenses', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('9544.22'), 'description': 'Accrue Amazon AWS Service Dec 23'}, {'gl': '3080', 'gl_name': 'Accrue Audit fees', 'id': '1.24E+04', 'period': '12', 'year': '2023', 'posting_date': '12/31/2023', 'amount': Decimal('1207.00'), 'description': 'Accrue Audit fees 2023'}]
matched = []

# Function to find transactions that sum up to zero within a GL
def find_zero_sum_transactions(transactions):
    # combines the transactions per GL
    gl_dict = {}
    for transaction in transactions:
        gl = transaction['gl']
        if gl not in gl_dict:
            gl_dict[gl] = []
        gl_dict[gl].append(transaction)

    # important to stop rematching those amounts that were already found as matches
    matched_indices = set()
    # just to show progress, since the program runs super slow
    total_gl = len(gl_dict)
    processed_gl = 0

    # for every transaction in a given GL:
    for gl, gl_transactions in gl_dict.items():
        amounts = [item['amount'] for item in gl_transactions]
        matched_indices = set()
        
        # for every amount in the GL
        for r in range(1, len(amounts) + 1):
            # Skip processing this GL if it's already matched
            if gl in matched_indices:
                break  

            # try all possible combinations    
            for subset in combinations(amounts, r):
                # if matched to zero, note the indexes
                if sum(subset) == Decimal('0'):
                    matching_indices = [i for i, trans in enumerate(gl_transactions) if trans['amount'] in subset]
                    if all(index not in matched_indices for index in matching_indices):
                        # If all indices in the subset are not yet matched, add them to 'matched_indices'
                        matched_indices.update(matching_indices)
                        matched.extend([{'Label': 'matched', **trans} for i, trans in enumerate(gl_transactions) if i in matching_indices])
                        print(f"Match found for GL {gl}: {subset}")
        processed_gl += 1
        print(f"Progress: {processed_gl+1}/{total_gl} GLs processed.")

# Find and store matches
find_zero_sum_transactions(my_list)

# Identify unmatched transactions 
unmatched = [item for item in my_list if item not in matched]
```

[image: ideal outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
my_list = [{'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-55.66'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-69.99'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-71'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-72.13'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-76'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-76.52'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-76.8'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-86.58'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-92'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-115.85'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '119.4'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '119.4'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-119.4'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-119.4'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-119.4'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-130.55'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-135.68'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-140.25'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-157.43'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-180.91'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-183.93'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-196.81'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '198.35'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-198.35'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-198.35'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-243.68'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-277.2'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '296.3'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-325.84'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-336.43'}, {'gl': '1900', 'amount': '-423.03'}, {'gl': 
'1900', 'amount': '2162.36'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '6647.27'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-6647.27'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '7552.31'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-7552.31'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '23746.02'}, {'gl': 
'2000', 'amount': '-23746.02'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-26610.79'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-40713.44'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '58755.19'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-58755.19'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-126974.74'}, {'gl': '2000', 'amount': '-216289.85'}, {'gl': '2100', 'amount': '28921.90'}, {'gl': '2100', 'amount': '9544.22'}, {'gl': '2200', 'amount': '1207.00'}, {'gl': '2300', 'amount': '674.86'}, {'gl': '2300', 'amount': '51004.10'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '222.81'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '344.53'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '992.73'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '17466.00'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '26881.00'}, {'gl': '2400', 'amount': '29704.77'}, 
{'gl': '2400', 'amount': '53867.12'}, {'gl': '2450', 'amount': '-1086.60'}, {'gl': '2500', 'amount': '-66588.09'}, {'gl': '2900', 'amount': '1839.00'}, {'gl': '3000', 'amount': '-520'}, {'gl': '3000', 'amount': '-6647.27'}, {'gl': '3000', 'amount': '32570.75'}, {'gl': '3000', 'amount': '-58755.19'}, {'gl': '3000', 'amount': '173031.88'}, {'gl': '3100', 'amount': '5345.24'}, {'gl': '3200', 'amount': '3817.37'}, {'gl': '3300', 'amount': '-350'}, {'gl': '3300', 'amount': '-1316.66'}, {'gl': '3400', 'amount': '-51004.10'}, {'gl': '3400', 'amount': '-28921.90'}, {'gl': '3500', 'amount': '-9544.22'}, {'gl': '3500', 'amount': '-1207.00'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '107.83'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-150'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-150'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-227.7'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-236.8'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-254.97'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-386.61'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-515.9'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-1026.49'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-1559.30'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-1787.30'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '1787.30'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-1949.83'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '11722.74'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-12397.26'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-67729.89'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '-82300.08'}, {'gl': '3600', 'amount': '227639.57'}, {'gl': '3650', 'amount': '-57.12'}, {'gl': '3700', 'amount': '-6546.65'}, {'gl': '3800', 'amount': '12397.26'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '-100'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '100'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '-300'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '-550'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '-1404.52'}, {'gl': '3900', 'amount': '-1787.30'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '116.49'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '227.7'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '381.3'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '1509.87'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': 
'1896.50'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '2066.50'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '-2486.47'}, {'gl': '3950', 'amount': '2486.47'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '6.73'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '-6.73'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '41019.55'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '75467.56'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '117672.02'}, {'gl': '3960', 'amount': '-227554.53'}, {'gl': '3970', 'amount': '-69.85'}, {'gl': '3980', 'amount': '1353.65'}, {'gl': '3990', 'amount': '76408.56'}]

# create a dict like {gl: (i, amount)}
gl_dict = dict.fromkeys([i['gl'] for i in my_list], tuple())
for i, d in enumerate(my_list):
    gl_dict[d['gl']] += ((i, float(d['amount'])),)
final_dict = {k: list(v) for k, v in gl_dict.items()}

def find_solutions(nums: list[tuple[int, float]], ex_l, ex_r) -> list[list[tuple[int, float]]]:
    solutions = []

    # perform pass throughs with preset rr and ll
    for ll in range(ex_l):
        for rr in range(len(nums) - 1, len(nums) - ex_r, -1):
            l = ll + 1
            r = rr - 1
            while nums[r][1] > 0 and nums[l][1] < 0:   # these are adjusted to ignore the index
                l_sum = sum([i[1] for i in nums[ll:l]])  
                r_sum = sum([i[1] for i in nums[r:rr]])
                if abs(l_sum + r_sum) < 0.001:  # account for floating point errors
                    solutions.append(nums[ll:l] + nums[r:rr])
                    l += 1
                elif l_sum + r_sum > 0:
                    if l - ll == ex_l:
                        break
                    l += 1
                else:
                    if rr - r == ex_r:
                        break
                    r -= 1

    return solutions

def smart_permutations(l: list) -> list[list]:  # returns a list n * 2 long 
    rev = list(reversed(l))
    n = len(l)
    temp = [0] * n
    output = []
    index_map = [i // 2 if i % 2 == 0 else n + (-i // 2) for i in range(n)]
    
    for _ in range(n - 1):  # perform this many cycles
        for i in range(n):
            temp[i] = l[index_map[i]]
        output.append(temp)
        l = temp
        temp = [0] * n
    for _ in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            temp[i] = rev[index_map[i]]
        output.append(temp)
        rev = temp
        temp = [0] * n
    return output

for gl, nums in final_dict.items():   # remember, nums is now in the form [(i, amount), ...]
    sols = set()
    positives = [i for i in nums if i[1] > 0]
    negatives = [i for i in nums if i[1] < 0]
    len_n, len_p = len(negatives), len(positives)  
    pos_perms = smart_permutations(positives)
    for perm in smart_permutations(negatives):
        for other in pos_perms:
            sols |= set(map(tuple, find_solutions(perm + perm + other + other, len_n, len_p)))

    # remove solutions that are basically repeats
    filtered_sols = set()
    sums = set()
    for s in sols:   # s is in shape tuple[tuple[int, float]]
        abs_sum = sum([abs(i[1]) for i in s]) 
        if abs_sum in sums:
            continue 
        sums.add(abs_sum)
        filtered_sols.add(s)
    
    # remove solutions that use already used up values
    final_sols = set()
    for s in sorted(filtered_sols, key=len, reverse=True):  # consider the longest ones first
        old = nums.copy()
        skip = False
        for x in s:
            try:
                old.remove(x)
            except ValueError:
                skip = True
                break
        if skip:
            continue
        nums = old
        final_sols.add(s)
    print(f"GL {gl}: {final_sols}")
```

This is what I got; it runs pretty quick (about half a second) but scales pretty poorly as it has something like a (n^4) time complexity (still better than messing with combinatorics though). Here's the output:

```
GL 1900: {((1, -69.99), (29, -336.43), (2, -71.0), (28, -325.84), (3, -72.13), (26, -277.2), (4, -76.0), (25, -243.68), (5, -76.52), (24, -198.35), (6, -76.8), (23, -198.35), (7, -86.58), (21, -196.81), (8, -92.0), (20, -183.93), (9, -115.85), (11, 119.4), (10, 119.4), (31, 2162.36), (27, 296.3))}
GL 2000: {((35, -7552.31), (41, -58755.19), (37, -23746.02), (40, 58755.19), (36, 23746.02), (34, 7552.31)), ((33, -6647.27), (32, 6647.27))}
GL 2100: set()
GL 2200: set()
GL 2300: set()
GL 2400: set()
GL 2450: set()
GL 2500: set()
GL 2900: set()
GL 3000: set()
GL 3100: set()
GL 3200: set()
GL 3300: set()
GL 3400: set()
GL 3500: set()
GL 3600: {((82, -1787.3), (83, 1787.3))}
GL 3650: set()
GL 3700: set()
GL 3800: set()
GL 3900: set()
GL 3950: {((105, -2486.47), (106, 2486.47))}
GL 3960: {((108, -6.73), (107, 6.73))}
GL 3970: set()
GL 3980: set()
GL 3990: set()
```

Edit: When you have more than about 20-30 nums per GL, this stops being as useful because the `smart_permutations` function becomes worse and worse of a representation of possible combinations.

Edit 2: Here is the updated version which preserves the index.

Let me know in a comment if the output is wrong, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Note: a lot of your transactions seem to match in magnitude (i.e. positive and negative of the same number) but this also works for transactions that do not have the same magnitude (like -4, -3, and +7)

Comment: yes I see that, it also picks up those matches where many items add up to 0. But is it showing every possible combination in a pair of () in the end? I'm not really understanding, because there are 5 x 119,40 (3 negative, 2 positive) in my_list for GL 1900, but the first set shows 4 of them offset. So there would only be one left. the second set uses 2 x 119,40, but there are not that many instances left? Maybe I'm looking at this wrong?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't "use up" the balances, but this can be implemented by modifying the `nums` array by removing found balances

Comment: @Schlossie I've updated the code to remove solutions that use up values, check it out

Comment: Thank you!!! I still have a lot of learning to do, before I understand your code, but it finds the right matches. Is there any way of preserving the index, the matching values had in the original my_list? That way I could still access all the supplementary information for each match. And by default unmatched are all remaining indexes. (see screenshot for what supplementary data there is). But if not possible, that's ok too. This helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you'll just need to adjust a lot of indexing (mostly in the `find_soutions` function, the `smart_permutations` function doesn't care about what you input) to make sure the amounts are getting properly addressed. For example, you can build your `gl_dict` by pointing each `gl` value to a list of corresponding dictionaries, rather than a list of amounts. Then, you have to change how sums get determined, and how things get filtered when creating the `final_sols` list. It's definitely possible but it can be difficult

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the function may miss some values at higher list sizes, as compromises were made to get good performance. If this is an issue, I think the smart_permutations function can be adjusted to generate more permutations

Comment: I updated the answer to save the index; here it is and also the updated output

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, to get the matches, you can try something like below :

```
from itertools import product

matches = [
    ((idxl, dl), (idxr, dr)) # can be adjusted if necessary
    for (idxl, dl), (idxr, dr) in product(enumerate(my_list[0]), repeat=2) 
    if dl["gl"] == dr["gl"] and float(dl["amount"]) == -float(dr["amount"])
]
```

Output :

```
print(f"{len(matches)} matches.")

for i, ((idxl, dl), (idxr, dr)) in enumerate(matches, 1):
     print(
         f"match n{i:02} =>",
         f"[{idxl:03}", "|", f"{dl['gl']:<5}", "|", f"{dl['amount']:<10}]", "-"*5,
         f"[{idxr:03}", "|", f"{dr['gl']:<5}", "|", f"{dr['amount']:<10}]",
     )
```

```
32 matches.
match n01 => [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [012 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n02 => [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [013 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n03 => [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [014 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n04 => [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [012 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n05 => [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [013 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n06 => [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ] ----- [014 | 1900  | -119.4    ]
match n07 => [012 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n08 => [012 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n09 => [013 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n10 => [013 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n11 => [014 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [010 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n12 => [014 | 1900  | -119.4    ] ----- [011 | 1900  | 119.4     ]
match n13 => [022 | 1900  | 198.35    ] ----- [023 | 1900  | -198.35   ]
match n14 => [022 | 1900  | 198.35    ] ----- [024 | 1900  | -198.35   ]
match n15 => [023 | 1900  | -198.35   ] ----- [022 | 1900  | 198.35    ]
match n16 => [024 | 1900  | -198.35   ] ----- [022 | 1900  | 198.35    ]
match n17 => [032 | 2000  | 6647.27   ] ----- [033 | 2000  | -6647.27  ]
match n18 => [033 | 2000  | -6647.27  ] ----- [032 | 2000  | 6647.27   ]
match n19 => [034 | 2000  | 7552.31   ] ----- [035 | 2000  | -7552.31  ]
match n20 => [035 | 2000  | -7552.31  ] ----- [034 | 2000  | 7552.31   ]
match n21 => [036 | 2000  | 23746.02  ] ----- [037 | 2000  | -23746.02 ]
match n22 => [037 | 2000  | -23746.02 ] ----- [036 | 2000  | 23746.02  ]
match n23 => [040 | 2000  | 58755.19  ] ----- [041 | 2000  | -58755.19 ]
match n24 => [041 | 2000  | -58755.19 ] ----- [040 | 2000  | 58755.19  ]
match n25 => [082 | 3600  | -1787.30  ] ----- [083 | 3600  | 1787.30   ]
match n26 => [083 | 3600  | 1787.30   ] ----- [082 | 3600  | -1787.30  ]
match n27 => [093 | 3900  | -100      ] ----- [094 | 3900  | 100       ]
match n28 => [094 | 3900  | 100       ] ----- [093 | 3900  | -100      ]
match n29 => [105 | 3950  | -2486.47  ] ----- [106 | 3950  | 2486.47   ]
match n30 => [106 | 3950  | 2486.47   ] ----- [105 | 3950  | -2486.47  ]
match n31 => [107 | 3960  | 6.73      ] ----- [108 | 3960  | -6.73     ]
match n32 => [108 | 3960  | -6.73     ] ----- [107 | 3960  | 6.73      ]
```

Comment: Wow, so elegant

Comment: If those few lines are all that I need then absolutely elegant! But I only see matching pairs (meaning same amount)? It is not finding multiple lines that add up to zero, is it? It is a bit beyond my python level :)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, not me. And I realize that you worked on a solution while I prepared the screenshot, which may have clarified. It just took a long time to come up with a second dataset that I could publish, sorry about that. I think your solution looks super tight and elegant. Just need one more set of matches in it, those that don't directly offset 1:1, but 1:many (see screenshot).

Comment: I can't find the SS. If you want to see more matches, try removing `dl["gl"] == dr["gl"] and`